# Java - GridBagLayout position JLabel

Tags: java, swing, awt, gridbaglayout

I use a `GridBagLayout` and place a `JLabel` on it as the picture shows. I managed to set the size of the `JLabel` to the desired one via `ipadx` and `ipady` but I don't seem to work with the position of it. It seems it is always centered on the middle while I'd like to start from the red dot and don't reposition itself as I resize the window. What should I do?

[image]

Thanks. The code I use is also:

```
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
setLayout(gbl);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

JLabel jl = new JLabel("This is a jlabel!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
jl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
gbc.ipadx = 87;
gbc.ipady = 220;
add(jl, gbc);
```

Comment: Play with the anchor and the fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I improved it... now you can work with insets to position that label around `JFrame`, but after some research I would recommend to choose different [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

So your code would look like:

```
Dimension d = new Dimension(350, 400);
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Heloo");
frame.setLayout(gbl);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

JLabel jl = new JLabel("This is a jlabel!", SwingConstants.CENTER);
jl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
gbc.ipadx = 87;
gbc.ipady = 220;
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 360, 340);// here work with JFrame size!!
```

Hope this code will help you :)

Comment: It did! Thanks so much! If I resize the window it appears to move as well tho. Do you have any solution for this last one? ;)

Comment: Change layout manager... or     set frame.setResizable(false).